# Excel 2007-VBA, Right Click Buttons

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am having a strange Excel 2007 issue, and I am not quite sure how to explain this. So bear with me please....

I have created a few right click buttons to call various backend VBA functions that I have written. They were working fine earlier today, and now for some reason,  a button is appearing that is not from the code in my worksheet. When you click it, it is attempting to open another worksheet and execute code from it. The two files are not in the same directory nor are they named anything similar. I deleted the file that the button is trying to execute from and now it just simply gives me an error 400.

So, I couldn’t figure that out, and have since deleted every single scrap of code in the backend of this file, and the button still appears. Any ideas what could be causing this? It seems like maybe its mixing files up or saving a copy somewhere in a temp directory and trying to access that instead of the actual code that is written in the VBA. Is there a cache I need to clear out or something?

I know I didn’t exactly do a great job describing this, so I will be more than happy to provide any and all other details that you may need. Just let me know what is going on.

**EDIT #1 -- New Information ==**
I can even open a new, completely blank excel file and the right click button is still there.

**EDIT #2 -- Tried Diagnostics ==**
I just tried running the Excel diagnostics and it found no problems. It is strange, it is like this macro has somehow became global or stored in some type of cache or something.

Comment: Did you look in the base template for 2007? It almost sounds like you were hit with an attack or a virus.

Comment: I don't think that is what the problem is. The button that is appearing is something that I wrote for a completely different Excel file. The file that it is trying to open is a file that I created. As far as the base template is concerned, I haven't ever messed with it, where would that be located at?

Comment: if you open the VBA editor using Alt+F11 you should see on the left a list of projects. If there are projects there that were added globally you should see them there as well as the project for your current work book. I am betting that somehow your button code was added globally.

Comment: I looked it up, the project that holds global or 'personal' macros is PERSONAL.XLSB. If you added a macro here it will be available in all pages.

Comment: Yeah, I knew about the PERSONAL files and none of them are showing up. Like i said an edit of my above description. I can open a brand new, never touched, no code whatsoever in the back end and the button is still appearing. I even went into the VBA editor and confirmed that this project is the only one, there are no PERSONAL.XLSB's there. No code at all. And when you right click the button still appears. This is by far the strangest and most hard-to-diagnose issue I have ran across in a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I'm understanding your issue correctly.

If you know what right-click (context) menus the button is appearing in you should be able to fix them with a `Reset` command. For example if it's appearing in the Cell context menu, you could try this in the VBE's Immediate window:

```
Application.Commandbars("Cell").Reset
```

This will reset the entire menu to its default state.

Also, you might be interested in a tool I wrote, [MenuRighter](http://yoursumbuddy.com/menurighter/), that allows you to tweak your right-click menus. It also has a setting to show you the Caption and ID of any context menu.

Comment: In my original script, I was using that command. However, the issue is that even in a brand new, never edited .xlsm file, the right click menu is still appearing even though there is no code that is creating it in the project.

Comment: I misread part of your response. By running that command in the Immediate Window. It fixed the problem. Thanks again. This had me scratching my head for the better part of the morning.